# Issue with DATEDIF function

Tags: excel, function, formula

DATEDIF function giving different values as shown in the snapshot.
Why this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should avoid passing `D2` directly to `DATEDIF` formula.
`DATEDIF` requires first 2 arguments as a date. You pass 0 and `D2` (`C2`-`B2`). Since lowest possible date in excel is 01-Jan-1900 and it is = 1, your arguments are 0 = 0-Jan-1900 (non existing date) and 546 = 29-Jun-1900. You would get more errors in calculation if your dates would include leap year (1900 is not leap year)

Also consider looking at [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/datedif-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c) as it states there are issues with "md" argument (see "Known issues").

So correct formula would be:

```
=DATEDIF(B2,C2,"y")&" years "&DATEDIF(B2,C2,"ym")&" months "&DATEDIF(B2,C2,"md")&" days"
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Answer is excellent; however, I need to convert number of days to "--Years--Months--Days" format as I am working in HR department, mostly calculating the percentages of working days.